# VB does not see Table after DoCmd.TransferDatabase using OpenRecordset

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using Do.CMD.TransferDatabase to copy in two tables from a second access database.  The TransferDatabase command runs, and I see the table in the Access list of tables, but the VB code doesn't see it.

I suspect I've messed up the internal list of tables because I see  the tables (
myTable
myTable1
myTable2)

If I leave a table there on purpose, Access seems to "see" the table enough to not over-write it and Access writes a copy, but then the same code does not see the existing table to openit.
Code snippets (sanitized):

```
{       
Dim ws As Workspace
Dim myDB As Database
Set myDB = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)


DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", filename, acTable,"myTable", "myTable", False

Dim OriginalInformation As Recordset
Set OriginalInformation = myDB.TableDefs("myTable").OpenRecordset
```

The code stops on the last line and give the error that the item is not found in the collection.

How do I copy in a table and then look at the contents within the same VB function?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use myDB.TableDerrs.Refresh between the import and using the 
myDB.TableDefs("myTable").OpenRecordset